# Setting Up Custom Rewrite Rule in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal is to transform urls from /t/code.png to /t/?t=code for use in my email tracking.

Following the examples in other answers, I've added the following rewrite to my functions.php.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^/?t/(.*).png$', 't/?t=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

And saved permalinks, but it redirects to 404 page.

I also tried adding it directly to my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?t/(.*).png$ t/?t=$1 [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

And restarted Apache2 but still it redirects to 404 page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '/' character before the '?'.
*/t/?t=code* becomes */t?t=code*